# Can I bundle my JavaScript code with an MIT licensed code and keep my code unaffected from the MIT license?

Tags: licensing, jquery, mit-license, software-distribution, bundling

Can I bundle my proprietary JavaScript code with MIT licensed libraries (e.g. JQuery, AngularJS) into the same file, distribute it via HTTP but disallow my users to use my own code as an MIT licensed code?

This way I could minimize the number of browser requests, and reduce errors due to network errors. I don't want to let my users copy, modify and reuse my own code outside of my website.

Comment: What do you mean "retain copyright"?  In order to license anything, you must have the copyright.  Whether you apply a BSD license, a MIT license, a GPL license, or a closed source license you'll still retain copyright, you'll just be granting different rights to those that acquire your code.  Is your question really about retaining copyright?  Or about something else like not granting certain rights to users of your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Publish a software with copyright and license](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/173506/publish-a-software-with-copyright-and-license)

Comment: I fixed my question. It's indeed not about copyright. I meant whether they have right to use, copy, modify and distribute my code just like the bundled MIT licensed code. I.e. does boundling makes my code MIT licensed or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Just specify the terms of your license with the accompanying code.

The MIT license doesn't have any provisions in it that forces *your* code to be MIT licensed, nor does it prevent you from relicensing the MIT-licensed code in any way you see fit.

Comment: Thanks! My question is also whether if I put the code into the same minimized JavaScript file, is my code considered separated? Let's say I have a comment line in the js saying that the code below is owned by me and the only licenae i give the users is to execute it by the browser on my own site or something.

Comment: See my edit.  Only copyleft licenses like GPL prevent you from relicensing the code in a more restrictive manner, regardless of the manner in which you mix your code with the MIT code.